# Testing mapbox-gl map fails in test because theres no WebGL

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, leaflet, webgl, mapbox

I use mapbox-gl, specifically mapbox-gl-leaflet, in React to create a map:

```
import Leaflet from 'leaflet'
import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css'
import {} from 'mapbox-gl-leaflet'
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'

const Map = () => {
    const map = useRef(null)

    useEffect(() => {

        Leaflet.mapboxGL({
            accessToken: token,
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/outdoors-v11',
        }).addTo(map.current)
    })
}
```

In the test it already fails when I try to mount `<Map />` with this error:

> Failed to initialize WebGL.

There are also two other Error messages:

> Error: Not implemented: HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext (without installing the canvas npm package) ...

> This page appears to be missing CSS declarations for Mapbox GL JS, which may cause the map to display incorrectly. Please ensure your page includes mapbox-gl.css, as described in https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/.

But as you can see I import the CSS file. I think the problem is that in Jest there is no WebGL available. I also installed the `canvas` npm package, but it didn't seem to help.
**Is it possible to somehow mock WebGL?** I already tried it with [jest-canvas-mock](https://github.com/hustcc/jest-canvas-mock). I importet it in the test file: `import {} from 'jest-canvas-mock'`. But I still get the `Error: Not implemented: HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext ...` error.

Comment: Use [puppeteer](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/puppeteer)?

Comment: These are mapbox and/or leaflet that need to be mocked. Jest uses fake DOM that can't and won't behave like a real thing and falls apart as soon as you do something complex. Third-party libs that deeply rely on how real browsers work should be mocked.

Comment: Error: Not implemented: HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext ... This error I solved adding window.HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext = () => {} before mount the component.

Comment: Currently I have the same error of WebGL.